# MySQL: is it possible to select all orders totals and calculate labor cost from 3 tables for a period of time listed hourly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables (Orders, Users and Users work times)

> and I'm trying to sum some totals, and calculate Labor Cost hourly for a period using a single query.

Eg: Labor Cost = ((user work hours * user rate) / total)
For the needed period, listed by hours like this:

```
Hour            Total      Qty       LC  
09:00 - 10:00   $53        18        $25  
10:00 - 11:00   $60        22        $24  
12:00 - 13:00   ....  
13:00 - 14:00   ....
```

The needed period comes from a DATETIME **k_orders created_on**
The hourly brakes (10:00 - 11:00) comes from (a DATETIME) **k_orders created_on**
The hourly rate comes from (a FLOAT, eg: 4.52) **k_users hourly_rate**
And the worked hours comes from (a DATETIME) **k_users_clock_inout clock_in / clock_out**

**Different users have different rates** and hours must be calculated separately for each user.

Also the period can be a month, or for example all Mondays of last 2 months.

The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `k_orders` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `store` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `canceled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `paid` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_qty` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `k_users_clock_inout` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `clock_in` datetime NOT NULL,
  `clock_out` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `k_users` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `hourly_rate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

> A question: Is this possible in a single query ?

Each time I try to do it i stuck, like for example last stuck:

```
SELECT HOUR(`created_on`) hour, SUM(O.total) total, SUM(O.total_qty) qty, (SUM(O.total) / SUM(O.total_qty)) average,
(
    SELECT SUM(total_rate / total) FROM (
        SELECT SUM(user_rate) total_rate FROM (
            SELECT SUM( (TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , C.clock_in, C.clock_out ) / 60) * U.hourly_rate) user_rate
            FROM `k_users_clock_inout` C 
            LEFT JOIN k_users U ON U.id = C.user_id
            WHERE 
                TIME(C.clock_in) BETWEEN hour AND (hour + 1) 
                AND 
                TIME(C.clock_out) BETWEEN hour AND (hour + 1) 
                AND U.hourly_rate > 0
            GROUP BY C.user_id
        ) as subsubquery
    ) as subquery
) lc
FROM `k_orders` O
WHERE
    O.paid = 1 AND
    O.canceled = 0 AND
    O.created_on BETWEEN '2016-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-10 00:00:00' AND
    O.store IN (3)
GROUP BY HOUR(`created_on`)
ORDER BY HOUR(`created_on`)
```

and when I was on the WHERE part, trying to add interval to the current hour *TIME(C.clock_in) BETWEEN hour AND (hour + 1)* (not working, I know) I realized that I cannot use aliases within more then one sub query... And I stuck again, but deadlines aren't moving forward, so any help is highly appreciated.

Example of wanted result for a month period (O.created_on BETWEEN '2016-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-10 00:00:00'):

```
hour  total  qty  average   lc
7     1.80   2    0.900000  329.84888887555553
8     2.20   2    1.100000  269.87636362545453
9     2.70   3    0.900000  164.92444443777777
10    71.33  20   3.566500  22.83569230676923
11    321.66 63   5.105714  34.1222988491954
........
21    834.38 174  4.795287  28.272761903619045
22    77.85  14   5.560714  8.457663817321937
```

Demo SQL data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tz2oeecfn81szjk/atest.sql?dl=0

Comment: please add a few rows of sample data

Comment: just added sample of wanted result set for a month period search

Comment: that's sample output, I was talking about sample data from the tables. (btw, do you have two sets of sample output or did I misunderstand?)

Comment: see my [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38899464)

Comment: @e4c5, I am preparing sample data just now...

Comment: @e4c5, thank you. I just add demo sql data

Comment: did you try that answer.I want to  know whether it is working or not?

Comment: yep, i try it. no. it does not work. gives me NULLs in the lc column. i commented it under the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot your query and modified like this.But you have to simplify the query.Even though it is giving results but this is not the correct way..

```
    SET @hor := 
(SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(HOUR(`created_on`)) 
FROM
  k_orders o 
WHERE O.paid = 1 
  AND O.canceled = 0 
  AND O.created_on BETWEEN '2016-09-01 00:00:00' 
  AND '2016-10-01 00:00:00' 
  AND O.store IN (3)) ;


SELECT HOUR(`created_on`) HOUR1, SUM(O.total) total, SUM(O.total_qty) qty, (SUM(O.total) / SUM(O.total_qty)) average,
(
    SELECT SUM(total_rate / total) FROM (
        SELECT SUM(user_rate) total_rate FROM (
            SELECT SUM( (TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , C.clock_in, C.clock_out ) / 60) * U.hourly_rate) user_rate
            FROM `k_users_clock_inout` C 
            LEFT JOIN k_users U ON U.id = C.user_id
            WHERE 
                HOUR(C.clock_in) BETWEEN (SELECT HOUR(created_on)   FROM k_orders WHERE id = FIND_IN_SET(HOUR(created_on),@hor) LIMIT 1)
              AND ((SELECT HOUR(created_on)  FROM k_orders WHERE id = FIND_IN_SET(HOUR(created_on),@hor) LIMIT 1) + 1) 
                AND 
                HOUR(C.clock_out) BETWEEN (SELECT HOUR(created_on)  FROM k_orders WHERE id = FIND_IN_SET(HOUR(created_on),@hor) LIMIT 1 ) AND ((SELECT HOUR(created_on)  FROM k_orders WHERE id = FIND_IN_SET(HOUR(created_on),@hor) LIMIT 1) + 1) 
                AND U.hourly_rate > 0 AND  REPLACE(@hor, CONCAT((SELECT HOUR(created_on)   FROM k_orders WHERE id = FIND_IN_SET(HOUR(created_on),@hor) LIMIT 1),',') , '')
            GROUP BY C.user_id
        ) AS subsubquery
    ) AS subquery
) lc
FROM `k_orders` O
WHERE
    O.paid = 1 AND
    O.canceled = 0 AND
   O.created_on BETWEEN '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND
    O.store IN (3)
GROUP BY HOUR(`created_on`)
ORDER BY HOUR(`created_on`)
```

Comment: where does the "in a single query" part fit in?

Comment: I just used a variable,Is that comes under two queries?

Comment: the select the comes after your variable `SET @hor := ` , how many values can that have?

Comment: It will get only one value

Comment: ok. As we are up under the question asking for his data, and never got it, I just find it hard to believe that you know that :p  That query could have 42 rows coming back as far as we know

Comment: I don't know. We have no data.

Comment: @ManchikantiAishwarya thank you! I was never using vars with sql queries and no idea, but when I execute both queries as is in phpmyadmin (SQL section) I'am having only "NULL"  for the entire "lc" column. eg - it's not working ? or I need to do something special for the vars?